# Build failed, project not deployed

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, maven-3, nexus

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project maven-web-application: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.mt:maven-web-application:war:2.0.7-20230110.202313-1 from/to nexus (http://172.31.7.102:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/): authentication failed for http://172.31.7.102:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/com/mt/maven-web-application/2.0.7-SNAPSHOT/maven-web-application-2.0.7-20230110.202313-1.war, status: 401 Unauthorized

I have double-checked my distribution management on my Pom file and settings.xml on both jenkins and maven and everything is 100% fine. It builds successfully on my local server but won't build on my jenkins pipeline. I have been on this issue for the last 4 days.  I need help

I have double-checked my distribution management on my Pom file and settings.xml on both jenkins and maven and everything is 100% fine. It builds successfully on my local server but won't build on my jenkins pipeline. I have been on this issue for the last 4 days.  please, I need help

Comment: Obviously it's not fine because `status: 401 Unauthorized`. Please show your distributionManagement part of your pom file and your settings.xml of course without passwords... Are you in a corporate environment?

Comment: Thank you, Khmarbaise for your response. Actually, I was able to fixed the issue. My maven server credential on my jenkins local server settings.xml file was accidentally commented out restricting it from deploying my built code to Nexus. After I corrected that my code was able to deploy successfully on jenkins pipeline.